# Checking if a previously selected rediobutton has been unchecked - Android Development

Tags: java, android

So I have the following code sample. This code would detect if a radio button has been selected. If hotdog_button has been selected then total is increased by 3 (later to be translated to a TextView $3.00).

```java
RadioButton hotdogBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hotdog_button);
RadioButton nachosBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.nachos_button);
...
View.OnClickListener hotdogListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addTotal(5);
            }
        };
View.OnClickListener nachosListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addTotal(4);
            }
        };
...
private void addTotal(int add) {
        total += add;
    }
```

How can I check if hotdogBtn has been released? Once the button has been released it would be passed to function subtractTotal (the opposite of add total), and then will update the TextView accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use `OnCheckedChangeListener` instead of `OnClickListener`

and examine the `isChecked` parameter to know whether the button is checked or unchecked

```
hotdogBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            addTotal(3);
        } else {
            subtractTotal(3);
        }
    }
});
```

If you necessary want to use `OnClickListener`, then you can check the same with `hotdogBtn.isChecked()`